# Using Linux sort for standard output results

Tags: linux, sorting, standards, output

So I have a program that prints out results onto the standard output (screen), is there a way to sort these results using the Linux sort?

Or is that sort only able to sort contents of a text file and hence I have to sort the file and then print the contents of the file to the standard output after that?

Comment: Stop thinking that "standard out" == "screen".  Thinking that they are equivalent is the root cause of many problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the commands from the terminal then you can use a pipeline to pipe the output to the `sort` command.
Take a look at this reference on [Piping](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pipe your program to sort as follows:

program_name | sort

If your program's output is of uniform field width you can pass options to sort to sort based on a specific column of your output.  If your output is not of uniform width, then your sorting may result in undesired results.

Sort can sort based on alphabet values as well as numeric values.  Check the man page on sort.

Hope that helps.